# Commutative matrices of order 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to give a simple proof of why $GL_n(K)$ spaces are not isomorphic for different $n$, by finding $2^n$ (I presume this is the maximal possible number) of pairwise commutative matrices who square to the identity. Do such matrices exist and is there a simple way to write them down?
Thank you.

Comment: In what sense are you using the term "isomorphic"? As groups, manifolds, other?

Comment: Sorry, I meant as groups.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the field $\mathbb K$ has a characteristic different from $2$. Then for $S\subset \{1,\dots,n\}$, define $D_S$ the diagonal matrix such that $D_S(i,i)=1$ if $i$ belongs to $S$ and $-1$ otherwise. This gives distinct pairwise commuting matrices whose square is the identity.

If $\mathcal F$ is a collection of pairwise commuting matrices and $F^2=I$ for all $F\in\mathcal F$, then there is a basis of $\mathbb K^n$ for which all the vectors of this basis are eigenvectors of $F$, $F\in\mathbb F$ arbitrary.

This proves that $\mathrm{card}(\mathcal F)\leqslant 2^n$.